# xcode 7.2 downloads but does not install

Tags: xcode, installation, app-store, updates

I went through the tedious download process via App Store. The row in the App Store Updates tab said Xcode was installed. But no sign of it in Applications folder.

When I go to the Purchased tab of App Store, the Xcode row has a button labeled "Install". So Xcode was *not* installed? OK, click this button. This just starts *another* 4 GB download. It seems that "install" means "download" and nothing actually installs.

What's up with the App Store? I poked around in the /private/var/.../com.apple.appstore folder but didn't see anything enlightening. I am now downloading the .dmg file directly from the Developer website. (Slow connection: 16 hr download!)

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, not strictly a programming question, but certainly an issue many iOS / OS X programmers are facing! I'm one of them.

I've had the same issue here. After looking long and hard around the web, I found that some people had issues with this update due to backup software.

I found that if I turned off Time Machine, rebooted, then the update went through fine. You also need about 12 Gb of free space to make it install properly too.

Hope this helps.